# ¿Como puedo remover un campo de un array multidimensional?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Verán tengo un array multidimensional y necesito remover un campo de dicho array pero no lo consigo.

Debo aclarar que estoy usando firestore de firebase.

Ese es mi código:

```
db.collection("database").doc("users").get().then(data => {
    var arrs = data.users;
    var remove = [{ name: "Juan" }, { name: "Alex" }]; // Este valor lo obtengo dependiendo de los checkbox's seleccionados
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
        var index = arrs[i].indexOf(remove);
        if (index !== -1) {
            newArr.push(data.users.splice(i, 0));
        }
    }
    db.doc("database/users").update({
        users: newArr
    });
});
```

Este es el JSON que me devuelve cuando hago el listado de los usuarios:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "Juan"
        "ave": 23
    }, {
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "name": "Josefina",
        "age": 18
    }, {
        "name": "Carla",
        "age": 25
    }]
}
```

Lo que se supone que me devolvería al remover las campos indicados, sería esto:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "Josefina",
        "age": 18
    }, {
        "name": "Carla",
        "age": 25
    }]
}
```

Necesito ayuda, llevo mas de 2hrs intentando hallar una solución. De ante mano muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `filter` para eliminar aquellos elementos indicados.

```js
let usersObj = JSON.parse(`{
    "users": [{
        "name": "Juan",
        "ave": 23
    }, {
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "name": "Josefina",
        "age": 18
    }, {
        "name": "Carla",
        "age": 25
    }]
}`);
    
    let filteredUsers=usersObj.users.filter(function(item) { 
   return item.name !== "Juan" && item.name !== "Alex";  
});
    
    console.log(filteredUsers);
```

[Más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

Comment: De esa manera funciona muy bien, pero me gustaría hacerlo buscando el valor en el array remove. Algo así return ítem.name !== remove.name;

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017949/761181

Comment: Genial!! Esto su me funciono como esperaba :D muchas gracias :)